# Insert data twice into the same table using cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I have two tables `cursor_created` and `cursor_copied` with the same columns. I want to fetch data from `cursor_created` and insert it into `cursor_copied` twice using a loop.

Query:

```
DECLARE @ID INT
DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Amount DECIMAL(18,0)
DECLARE @Date NVARCHAR(50)

DECLARE IDs CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT
        ID, Name, Amount, Date 
    FROM
        cursor_created 

OPEN IDs

FETCH NEXT FROM IDs into @ID, @Name, @Amount, @Date

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO cursor_copied (id, name, amount, date)
    VALUES (@ID, @Name, @Amount, @Date)
    ----Verify that Data in TestTable
    --print @ID 
    --print @Name
    --print @Amount
    --print @Date

    --SELECT @ID, @Name, @Amount, @Date FROM cursor_copied 
    FETCH NEXT FROM IDs into @ID, @Name, @Amount, @Date
END

CLOSE IDs
DEALLOCATE IDs
```

Output:

```
ID  Name  Amount  Date
------------------------------------------
1   A     2000    2008-03-15 18:15:43.000
2   B     3000    2008-03-15 18:15:43.000
3   C     4000    2008-03-15 18:15:43.000
```

I would like this instead:

```
ID  Name  Amount  Date
------------------------------------------
 1  A     2000    2008-03-15 18:15:43.000
 2  B     3000    2008-03-15 18:15:43.000
 3  C     4000    2008-03-15 18:15:43.000
 1  A     2000    2008-03-15 18:15:43.000
 2  B     3000    2008-03-15 18:15:43.000
 3  C     4000    2008-03-15 18:15:43.000
```

Comment: If you ALWAYS need to insert twice the same record (God and you know the reason for that), you can simply put the insert statement twice. Can't you?

Comment: offcourse i know the reason not you, and simply i know put the insert statement twice but i can't thats why i trying using loop , and that is    alreay metioned in title . you cant see??

Comment: That sounds more like an **exercise** than a projectal question. Am I right?

Comment: Can you give me a correct answer without ask any more questions?       no ? then please leave this

Comment: Your request is my command. Good luck!!!!

Comment: ohh Thankyou soo much

Comment: @FDavidov means, try to put 2 inserts statement like this INSERT INTO cursor_copied (id, name, amount, date)  VALUES (ID, Name, Amount, Date); INSERT INTO cursor_copied (id, name, amount, date)
    VALUES (ID, Name, Amount, Date); it's 2 times insert

Answer (score 1):

you should use `after insert` trigger.

you can set `on after insert` trigger on `cursor_inserted` table and control insert event on that table then insert duplicate row.

```
CREATE TRIGGER DublicateInsert ON cursor_copied 
AFTER INSERT  
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO cursor_copied (id, name, amount, date)
    SELECT id, name, amount, date
    FROM  INSERTED 
END
```

or you can use this syntax for your problems

```
INSERT INTO cursor_copied (id, name, amount, date)
OUTPUT inserted.id, inserted.name,inserted.amount,inserted.date
INTO cursor_copied (id, name, amount, date)
 VALUES (@ID, @Name, @Amount, @Date)
```

Comment: GO is is a batch separator understood by various applications and not a tsql command/function. In this case the number that follows GO is interpreted as a repetition number and SSMS (not the database engine) will execute the batch preceding GO the specified number of times. It would help enormously if you explain your suggestion - especially when it relies on rarely-used functionality.

Comment: Yes it's right  but i change it and found two way for do that job

Answer (score 1):

Using a cursor for this is a mistake.  You should use set operations where you can:

```
INSERT INTO cursor_copied (id, name, amount, date)
    SELECT ID, Name, Amount, Date 
    FROM cursor_created CROSS APPLY
         (VALUES (1), (2)) copies(n);
```

Even if you are learning about cursors, it is really important to learn when they are appropriate.  And they are almost never appropriate when the code can be replaced by a single query.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply rewrite your Insert as below inside the cursor:

```
INSERT INTO cursor_copied (id, name, amount, date)
    VALUES (@ID, @Name, @Amount, @Date),
           (@ID, @Name, @Amount, @Date)
```

BUT your selected solution might not be a good solution for this kind of problems. If you are interested about the other solutions, please read the following stories too.

**Solution 1**

refer to [@GordonLinoff's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50305629/1666800) answer

**Solution 2**

Lets go through the problem step by step:

First I suppose that, there is a two tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t1(Id INT, Name NVARCHAR(50), Amount DECIMAL(18,0), Date NVARCHAR(50))
GO
CREATE TABLE t1_copy(Id INT, Name NVARCHAR(50), Amount DECIMAL(18,0), Date NVARCHAR(50))
```

Then I suppose that, I have inserted the following records to `t1`:

```
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES
(1,'A', 2000,'2008-03-15 18:15:43.000'),
(2,'B', 3000,'2008-03-15 18:15:43.000'),
(3,'C', 4000,'2008-03-15 18:15:43.000')
```

Next I need to think about a query, which helps me produce the duplicated records. I have numerous options available, such as `Cross Apply` as @GordonLinoff mentioned. The other way is to use `UNION ALL` as follow:

```
SELECT t1.Id,
       t1.Name,
       t1.Amount,
       t1.Date FROM dbo.t1
UNION ALL
SELECT Id,
       Name,
       Amount,
       Date FROM dbo.t1;
```

This query will produce the desired result and what I need to do here, is to simply insert them into the destination table like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.t1_copy(Id,Name,Amount,Date)
SELECT t1.Id,
       t1.Name,
       t1.Amount,
       t1.Date FROM dbo.t1
UNION ALL
SELECT Id,
       Name,
       Amount,
       Date FROM dbo.t1;
```

That would be clear that before inserting into the table, you might need to pay attention to the `Primary Key` or `Identity` column, if exists!

**Solution 3**

You can make use of `GO`! like this:

```
   INSERT INTO dbo.t1_copy(Id,Name,Amount,Date)
   SELECT Id,Name,Amount,Date FROM dbo.t1
   GO 2
```

This is not what I would recommend, because GO is the batch separator and would put you in trouble. Also aforementioned query will be executed as two separate transaction which again could be a trouble point!

**Solution 4**

You can make use of `OUTPUT` operator. however due to complexity, again I do not recommend it. Like this:

```
   INSERT INTO dbo.t1_copy(Id,Name,Amount,Date)
   SELECT * FROM(
       INSERT INTO dbo.t1_copy(Id,Name,Amount,Date)
          OUTPUT Inserted.id, Inserted.Name, Inserted.Amount, Inserted.Date
       SELECT Id,Name,Amount,Date FROM dbo.t1) AS k
```

**What about using Cursor?**

[@GordonLinoff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50305629/1666800) mentioned the mistake point of using Cursor in this scenario, however if you insist on using Cursor, you will need to declare the cursor in `Fast_Forward` mode. Declaring it in `SCROLL` mode will not help you and will decrease the total performance of query!

```
DECLARE IDs CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR ...
```

**Performance Comparison:**

If we simply take a look at the execution plan of the aforementioned solutions, we will see that Solution 1 has a better performance output compared to other solution. In my PC the execution plan output is, as follow:

```
Solution 1 ====================> Subtree Cost: 0.0133
Solution 2 ====================> Subtree Cost: 0.0165
Solution 3 ====================> Subtree Cost: 0.0132*2=0.0264
Solution 4 ====================> Subtree Cost: 0.0232
Cursor in SCROLL mode =========> Subtree Cost: 0.0332
Cursor in Fast_Forward mode ===> Subtree Cost: 0.0203
```

These numbers would vary in your PC!